# How to filter SUM(flag) OVER (...) with having in sqlite

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, backend

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Q.Question_id, Q.Question, PMA.part_model_ans, QP.part_total_marks, MA.answer_mark, Q.rowid, 
         Q.Question <> LAG(Q.Question, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY Q.Question_id ORDER BY Q.rowid) flag
  FROM QUESTIONS Q
  LEFT JOIN QUESTIONS_PART QP ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id
  LEFT JOIN PART_MODEL_ANSWER PMA ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id
  LEFT JOIN MODEL_ANSWER MA ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
)
SELECT Question_id, Question, part_model_ans, part_total_marks, answer_mark, 
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Question_id ORDER BY rowid) part
FROM cte
having part = 1
ORDER BY question_id
```

What i would like to do is filter the part  so that it only shows the rows with  1 in it
however after using having part == 1 the expected result is still the same i do not know why it does not filter, where clause cannot be used due to misuse of aggregate

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to accomplish.  There may be other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the condition in a `WHERE` clause, but `part` is the result of a window function and you can't use it directly in the `WHERE` clause.

You can do it with a subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Q.Question_id, Q.Question, PMA.part_model_ans, QP.part_total_marks, MA.answer_mark, Q.rowid, 
         Q.Question <> LAG(Q.Question, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY Q.Question_id ORDER BY Q.rowid) flag
  FROM QUESTIONS Q
  LEFT JOIN QUESTIONS_PART QP ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id
  LEFT JOIN PART_MODEL_ANSWER PMA ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id
  LEFT JOIN MODEL_ANSWER MA ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT Question_id, Question, part_model_ans, part_total_marks, answer_mark, 
         SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Question_id ORDER BY rowid) part
  FROM cte
)
WHERE part = 1
ORDER BY question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the first question for each `Question_Id`.  If the questions are not repeated, then a simpler method is:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT Q.Question_id, Q.Question, PMA.part_model_ans, QP.part_total_marks, MA.answer_mark, Q.rowid, 
             FIRST_VALUE(Q.Question) OVER (PARTITION BY Q.Question_id ORDER BY Q.rowid) as first_question
      FROM QUESTIONS Q LEFT JOIN
           QUESTIONS_PART QP
           ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id LEFT JOIN
           PART_MODEL_ANSWER PMA
           ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id LEFT JOIN
           MODEL_ANSWER MA
           ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
     )
SELECT Question_id, Question, part_model_ans, part_total_marks, answer_mark
FROM cte
WHERE Question = first_question
ORDER BY question_id;
```